# Inconsistent capitalization of the word "Badge"

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar

On the [legend for the badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges), in the sidebar you have the word "Badges" capitalized in the description of Gold Badges, but the other badge descriptions have the word lowercased.

Comment: It's because Gold Badges are more important than other badges.

Comment: That explains why "Platinum BADGES" is spelled the way it is

Comment: Nice job, Anna -.-. @Community

Answer (score 2):

The word "Badges" in Gold badge's description is now updated with lower case.

> [image]

So it's [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now.

Comment: Retagged and flagged. :)

Comment: ...and Nick came for the rescue.